# Windows 7 VPN Client Default IPsec Configuration?

Tags: windows-7, ipsec, vpn

I'd like to use the windows vpn client for client-site vpn to my linksys rv042. As far as I can tell, the windows VPN client doesn't provide a lot of flexibility in its IPsec settings. Assuming full configurability on the site end of a client-site VPN configuration, does anyone how to configure the site to match the windows client?

Bonus points: how would I discover these settings for myself?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would set up a VPN in Windows 7. This will show you the variety of options available to you.

**1. Choose set up a vpn in the start menu**

[image: Start menu]

**2. Follow the wizard. Select "Don't Connect Now"**
[image: ms vpn wizard]

**3. Browse to network connections in Control Panel and Right-click your new connection and choose properties**
[image: network connections]

**4. Go to the security tab and select IPSEC.**
[image: Security tab]

**5. Click advanced settings and enter your PSK (Pre-Shared Key)**
[image]

You may need to adjust your settings a bit from there, but that should get you most of the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the built-in Windows 7 client, but the one from www.shrew.net.

Native client or not, on shrew.net they also have a description how to configure the netgear RVX to match the client.
http://www.shrew.net/support/wiki/HowtoLinksys

Combine the information from the first answer with the one in the link and maybe you'll get it working.